# Get time spent by process in Kernel space

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

**I am interested in how to do this in Windows**

The only API I found that could do this was `GetProcessTimes`. I returns true, fills the creation time and exit time structure, but the kernel and user time ones remain 0. I tried Sleeping, calling APIs that execute in kernel-mode thinking I could get it to change, but it remains 0.

I was running it with a pseudohandle `(HANDLE)-1)` a.k.a. `GetCurrentProcess()`, so I tried plain opening a handle to my own process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and also with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` thinking perhaps the API does not interpret the pseudohandle right, but it still does not work.

What can I do?

**The code for checking (I check the value of pKernelTime, not just the casted one):**

```
FILETIME pKernelTime{}, a{}, b{}, c{};
unsigned long time(0);
if (true == GetProcessTimes(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(-1), &a, &b, &pKernelTime,
    &c))
{
    time = (*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&pKernelTime)
        ) / 10000000ul);
}
```

**The code between the checks (file is 27mb)***

```
char* buff = new char[25000];
    DWORD read(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        HANDLE file = CreateFileA("a.dat", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
        ReadFile(file, (void*)buff, 25000, &read, nullptr);
        CloseHandle(file);
    }
    printf("%d\n", read);
```

Comment: What are you doing to keep the process busy (`Sleep` doesn`t count)?  Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I was indeed using sleep along with ReadProcessMemory calls. I will try a different method and see if it works. Thanks for the tip, man.

Comment: Try reading a big file one byte at a time via `ReadFile`.   That will hammer the CPU.

Comment: *"What can I do?"* - Not sure, you haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: Updated with the code. @IInspectable Was me saying that the KernelTime and UserTime structure were not filled by the call, while the others were and the function call returned true not enough?

Comment: You never said, that those output parameters didn't receive values. You said, the values were zero. That doesn't explain any sort of issue. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three issues with your code.  Firstly, this:

```
time = (*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&pKernelTime)
    ) / 10000000ul);
```

should be this:

```
time = (*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&pKernelTime)
    ) / 10000000ull);
```

Then, also, change `time` to be an `unsigned long long`.

Secondly, `time` as been truncated to a whole number of seconds.  This is probably not what you want - you need something more fine-grained than that.

Thirdly, to give your machine some real work to do, change this:

```
char* buff = new char[25000];
DWORD read(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    HANDLE file = CreateFileA("a.dat", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    ReadFile(file, (void*)buff, 25000, &read, nullptr);
    CloseHandle(file);
}
```

to this:

```
DWORD read(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    HANDLE file = CreateFileA ("a.dat", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    for (int j = 0; j < 25000; ++j)
    {
        BYTE ch;
        ReadFile(file, &ch, 1, &read, nullptr);
    }
    CloseHandle(file);
}
```

Because lots of small reads involve more work than a few large ones.

This combination of changes should allow you to actually measure something.

Comment: Yep.. Finally I am getting something. Thanks a lot, man... It appears I had to make my computer do a whole lot more work.